# Setup a Windows Domain on Azure and have my laptop be a part of it

Tags: networking, azure, vpn

I'm new to Azure Networking and not very familiar with Networking in general, so pardon my naivety.

My requirement is to set up a Windows Domain, which I understand is the phrase used to describe a network whose principals (machines, users, services etc) are tracked via a centralized database (usually Active Directory).

I understand that this can be done on Azure, and I can add virtual machines provisioned on Azure to this network. However, I would also like my laptop (and possibly other machines my team and I own) to be a part of the same network.

1. Is this possible on Azure?
2. Would I require a device as mentioned [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj156075.aspx) to set up something like this?

What I need this setup for is so that I can create an environment that allows us to replicate the environment our clients have (typical Corporate Windows Domains with Active Directory, Exchange Server etc). So even if the above is possible using Azure, but there are more effecient alternatives, I would love to know about them.

Thanks
Jaspreet

Answer (score 3):

What you really need is to create a virtual networking set in which you will add virtual machines on Windows Azure as well as physical machines from your on premise network.

To keep machines under one domain you can have domain controller (DC) running in Windows Azure Virtual Machines, or you can keep running DC on premise and connect with Azure Virtual Network.

Once you have DC established and you will have VPN based networking connection between your on premise machines and Azure VM. So when you bring your Laptop or any physical machine which is same Domain joined (DC in cloud/on-premise) then machine will be authenticated through the same DC which u have configured earlier. Keep in mind that any physical machine which is already domain joined will show up in same network as soon as your domain controller is configured with Azure Virtual Networking. That's all you need.

Here are step by step details for you to follow:

1. [Creating and Settings up a Virtual Network in Windows Azure](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/networking/create-a-virtual-network/)
2. [Adding a Virtual Machine to Virtual Network at Windows Azure](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/networking/add-a-vm-to-a-virtual-network/)
3. [Install a new Active Directory forest in Windows Azure](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/networking/active-directory-forest/)

   OR

   [Install a Replica Active Directory Domain Controller in Windows Azure Virtual Networks](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/networking/replica-domain-controller/)
4. https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/networking/cross-premises-connectivity/

Comment: Thanks for the answer Avkash. If I understand you correctly, option 1 (points 1, 2 and 3 above) is applicable when I do not have an on-premises domain controller where as option 2 (point 4) is applicable when I already have an on-premises domain controller and I want to add VMs provisioned on Azure to the domain. Is that accurate? If that is the case, option 1 is applicable to me.

Comment: Also, it wasn't clear to me whether you said that once I have the DC established in Azure (i.e. option 1), I can just add my laptop to the domain without any additional setup or whether I would have to set up a VPN (possible with a VPN device) to be able to add my laptop to the domain. Can you please clarify that point?